# Only accept primitive types in a Rust Generic

Tags: generics, rust

Is there a way I can have a Rust Generic only accept primitive types? I want to later iterate over the bits in the value, and I understand that that's only possible with primitive types.

```
struct MyStruct<T> {
    my_property: T // my_property HAS to be a primitive type
}
```

Comment: What on earth do you want to iterate over the bits for?

Comment: “Primitive types” is not a meaningful concept in Rust. There is the [`Copy`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/kinds/trait.Copy.html) kind, but that’s the closest you’ll get in that regards.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan To allow to transfer boolean values in a modular way. I could pre-set it to byte, short, int etc. but that wouldn't allow for an as modular design.

Comment: I still do not understand. What do you mean by “transfer boolean values in a modular way”? I think you may be trying to do something in a suboptimal way where there is a better way of doing it.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan Think of it as a bitmap without using the heap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the closest thing you can get is [`Primitive`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/num/trait.Primitive.html) trait which is implemented for in-built numeric types. It is a combination of several other numerical traits, which, in the end, allows for bit-fiddling with the values. You will also probably need to add `BitAnd`/`BitOr`/etc. traits, because `Primitive` only does not seem to allow these operations:

```
fn iter_bits<T: Primitive+BitAnd<T, T>+BitOr<T, T>>(x: T) { /* whatever */ }
```

Comment: As it seems, the Primitive trait was removed sometime after July 2014, so this solution doesn't work exaclty like this anymore and requires more than one line. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30044026/what-happened-to-stdnumprimitive for an update.

Answer (score 1):

Since you seem to have custom requirements, you could use a custom trait with the specific functionality you need, e.g.

```
trait BitIterate {
    /// Calls `f` on each bit of `self`, passing the index and the value.
    fn each_bit(&self, f: |uint, bool|);
}


impl BitIterate for u8 { ... }
impl BitIterate for u16 { ... }
// etc... could be done with a macro

// a non-primitive type which has a sensible way to iterate over bits
impl BitIterate for std::collections::Bitv { ... }
```

(That's one interpretation of "iterate over bits" anyway.)

Then, functions using `MyStruct` and needing iterable bits would use something like

```
fn print_bits<T: BitIterate>(x: MyStruct<T>) {
    x.my_property.each_bit(|index, bit_value| {
        println!("bit #{} is {}", index, bit_value);
    })
}
```