# What happened to std::num::Primitive?

Tags: rust

I found 
[Primitive](http://doc.rust-lang.org/0.12.0/std/num/trait.Primitive.html) through Google but it appears to be from a pre-beta version and my compiler (beta 3) complains that it can't find it. Can anyone point me to where it has moved or if there is an equivalent? Web searching hasn't thrown up anything promising

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It [was removed](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/24636), since it wasn't being used at the time.

You can write your own marker trait of the form, though.

Comment: Most of `std::num` traits was moved to [`num` crate](http://doc.rust-lang.org/num/num/index.html).

Comment: Yes, but not that one.

Comment: IIRC `Primitive` trait was just meta-trait for `Copy + Num + Bounded + NumCast + PartialOrd + Clone`.

Comment: Exactly. You can write your own marker trait like that if you want. That's my point.

Comment: ... but isn't that collection of traits actually the most common use case?  It would be nice to have a standard name for that.  Where's the harm?