# How to safely cast integers?

Tags: rust

There used to be a `fn std::num::cast` that would cast between integer types and return an `Option` (returning `None` if the cast was invalid). Where did that functionality go?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Similarily to previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30044026/what-happened-to-stdnumprimitive), that functionality moved to [num](https://crates.io/crates/num) crate. More precisely, It's in [num::traits::cast](http://doc.rust-lang.org/num/num/traits/fn.cast.html).